# DBpedia Lookup Service results in Portuguese

Tags: dbpedia

I'm using DBpedia Lookup, but whatever is the word I send, it always returns me results in English.

The query I'm using is: http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx

Is there a way to get the results in a specific language? I'd like it to be returned in Portugues.

Comment: It's not quite clear what your question is.  If you're using a SPARQL query, could you show it please?  Using SPARQL, you're able to filter strings based on language tags, so you'll be able to restrict yourself to Portuguese text.

Comment: I'm not using SPARQL. I just want to know if there's any Portuguese endpoint for Lookup. Dbpedia Spotlight, for example, has these one: http://spotlight.sztaki.hu:2228/rest, that only returns information in Potuguese. But a person called Pablo Mendes has already answered my question: "As far as I know there is no deployed lookup for Portuguese. But you can download the source could and build it yourself in your own machine. Or you can try to convince someone from dbpedia-portuguese@lists.sourceforge.net to deploy it under pt.dbpedia.org."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no deployed lookup for **Portuguese**. But you can **download** the source code and build it on your own machine.

Bye!